# Webview - open links in external apps and browsers / android

Tags: android, webview, external

I am a beginner in making android applications. I have made a web application in HTML which i want to be able to use in my application that I am making in android studio. I managed to make a simple web view in android studio which makes my web application work fine when i test it on my device. The only problem is that the web view handles all the URL´s inside my web application. The web application consists of tabs that directs me to different pages when i click on them which is what i want. But I have contact-buttons and different links that i want to be "released" from the web view. Lets take the contact button as an example. I have a Galaxy note which I am using to test my apps. When i open my application on my phone i see my Web application and i can navigate around. When i click the contact button, the web view handles the link and gives me a "page could not load" instead of opening the mail application on my phone. I also have buttons with links that I want to be able to open in an external browser on my phone. I hope you understand my problem and I am sorry for my bad english.

This is some of my code for the web view.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
    try {
        browser.loadUrl("http://WebAppURL");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**OurViewClient.java**

```
public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return true; 
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way implement your `WebViewClient` like

```
 private class VideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                System.out.println("url called:::" + url);
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }  else if (url.startsWith("http:")
                        || url.startsWith("https:")) {

                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
                     startActivity(intent);

                }  else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {

                    MailTo mt=MailTo.parse(url);

                    send_email(mt.getTo());

                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

and create send mail function like

```
   public void send_email(String email_add) {
    System.out.println("Email address::::" + email_add);

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { email_add });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    yourActivity.this.startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

}
```

Comment: I get `Error:(24, 17) cannot find symbol method startActivity(android.content.Intent)`and `Error:(58, 9) cannot find symbol method getActivity()`

Comment: The error disappeared but what about `Error:(24, 17) cannot find symbol method startActivity(android.content.Intent)`

Comment: @Stumpp i told you try this way `MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));`

Comment: @Stumpp better to post your code. I want to see how you integrate?

Comment: I made it work, but It seems like every link opens in external browser whether or not it contains http. I have these tabs in my web app that i want to open in the webview but now it opens in external. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My Code Working Good, just Remember the code line Sequence and placement.. Copy and paste code in your mainactivity.java file

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mywebView = findViewById(R.id.myview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("http://yourwebsitename.com");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());

}

class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public  boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("yourwebsitename.com")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
}
```