# Click in a Webview "Android" to open an externe application like facebook

Tags: android, html, webview

I created an application using Webview, and I make the all the links open in the same Webview, so if a user click a button with a link `tel:+135654452` nothing happen and a blank page with 404 error appear, instead of launching the Phone application to call directly. So my question is how to make the Webview open applications when I click in specific buttons in it?

I checked this link : [Webview - open links in external apps and browsers / android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869429/webview-open-links-in-external-apps-and-browsers-android#23869488)
But this won't help because every link opens in external browser! So this is not the answer.

Comment: This won't help because every link opens in external browser! So this is not the answer